# void androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.setVisibility(int) - on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

There is an error I'm facing that a **Null object reference** in **ConstraintLayout**

**Logcat**

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'void
> androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.setVisibility(int)'
> on a null object reference
> at com.dreamKatcher.Core.Profile.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:136)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2595)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
> at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:434)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2076)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1821)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2660)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2610)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1413)
> at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7169)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3146)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)

```
public class ProfileFragment extends AbstractBaseFragment implements ProfileView {

    @BindView(R.id.appBarMain)
    AppBarLayout appBar;

    @BindView(R.id.appBar)
    ConstraintLayout app_bar;

    @BindView(R.id.nameTextView)
    TextView nameTextView;

    @BindView(R.id.profileDescTextView)
    AppCompatTextView profileDescTextView;

    @BindView(R.id.detailsViewPager)
    CustomViewPager detailsViewPager;

    @BindView(R.id.detailsTabLayout)
    TabLayout detailsTabLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.nest)
    NestedScrollView nest;

    @BindView(R.id.profileImageView)
    CircularImageView profileImageView;

    @BindView(R.id.collapsingToolbar)
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;

    Unbinder unbinder;

    @BindView(R.id.settings)
    ImageView settings;

    @BindView(R.id.backButton)
    ImageView backButton;

    @BindView(R.id.title)
    TextView title;

    @BindView(R.id.search)
    ImageView search;

    @BindView(R.id.leader_board)
    ImageView leaderBoard;

    @BindView(R.id.typeandnickname)
    TextView typeandnickname;

    @BindView(R.id.img_prize)
    ImageView img_prize;

    @BindView(R.id.img_games)
    ImageView img_games;

    ProfilePresenter profilePresenter;

    public static String username;

    private ProfileViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    public ProfileFragment() {

    }

    public static ProfileFragment newInstance() {
        return new ProfileFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_profile, container, false);

        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        app_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        settings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        settings.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_games.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_prize.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        nest.setFillViewport(true);
       
        
    }

    private void setUpAppbarLayout() {

        appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener((appBarLayout, verticalOffset) -> {
            if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            } else {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

It's working perfectly for some time before, I didn't change anything in this class. How to solve this issue? Any suggestions would be helpful.

**EDIT 1**
Now the issue changed to TutorialActivity

```
public class TutorialActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.tutorial_viewpager)
    ViewPager tutorialViewpager;
    @BindView(R.id.pageindicator)
    PageIndicatorView pageindicator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        TutorialAdapter tutorialAdapter = new TutorialAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        tutorialViewpager.setAdapter(tutorialAdapter);

        tutorialViewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }
    }
    }
```

**Logcat**

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
> activity
> ComponentInfo{com.dreamKatcher/com.dreamKatcher.Core.Walkthrough.TutorialActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)'
> on a null object reference
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)'
> on a null object reference
> at com.dreamKatcher.Core.Walkthrough.TutorialActivity.onCreate(TutorialActivity.java:34)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7148)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7139)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1293)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)

**EDIT 2** I can now view the TutoriaActivity by removing the ButterKnife and added the layout default using `findViewById`
I'm using ButterKnife version 10.1.0, when I upgraded to latest version the issue is not resolved.

**EDIT 3**
activity_tutorial.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Core.Walkthrough.TutorialActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
        android:id="@+id/pageindicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
        app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
        app:piv_selectedColor="#33FFFFFF"
        app:piv_unselectedColor="@color/white"
        app:piv_viewPager="@id/tutorial_viewpager"
        attrs:piv_padding="1.5dp"
        attrs:piv_radius="4dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What about XML? Have you changed `ButterKnife` lib version or migrated to androidx? Comment `app_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and check if `settings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` will produce same error.

Comment: I changed the butterknife li version when this error occured

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked by changing the below lines of codes from onCreateView() method to onActivityCreated()

```
app_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
settings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
settings.setOnClickListener(this);
img_games.setOnClickListener(this);
img_prize.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: No, Let me try this

Comment: For the 2nd question, the id of the view pager tutorial_viewpager. Is that correct id which in .XML file?

Comment: yes, Because it's working fine until there is some point when it crashed

Comment: Can you please add XML file of `activity_tutorial` code?